# How to add extra input field(checkbox) to column header in Angular ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I want to put a checkbox in `ui-grid` column header to group row according to that column. I don't know how to add extra input field to column header. What would be the approach to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The headerCellTemplate property on the columnDef should let you control what you want in the header.  I'd also look at the menu item that grouping adds for grouping a column, you'd want to make the same call to group and ungroup the individual columns.